# AWS Lambda using node.js not executing promise function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I created this simple function  with two console.log calls. "After promise created" shown in log, while "scan promise executed" does not appear. I am new to node.js.  Where is my mistake?

```
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {

    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

    AWS.config.update({
        region: "us-east-1",
        endpoint: "https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    });

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();



    var params = {
        TableName: "User",
        KeyConditionExpression: null,
        FilterExpression: 'CusomerId = :customerid',

    };



    var scanPromise=docClient.scan(params).promise();
    console.log('\r\nAfter promise created');
    scanPromise.then(function(err,data)
    {
         console.log('\r\nScan promise executed');

    });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried returning `scanPromise` from the function. 
e.g. `return scanPromise.then(.....)`

Comment: Ok that does cause the promise to execute.  Although it causes a dynamodb access failure in log without hitting the console.log line in my code.

If you enter this in answer I can mark as answered.

Comment: I added it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handler` is an asynchronous function. If you don't return a promise, the handler will be executed but it will quit immediately without waiting for your promise to finish.

Change it to `return scanPromise.then(...)`

Comment: I have a similar issue, but this does not work for me. I've written it exactly as you suggested and posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518992/lambda-function-ends-after-call-to-dynamodb-using-promises-but-returns-no-error 

Could you provide any feedback?