# Lambda function ends after call to dynamoDB using promises, but returns no errors?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Lambda function reaching out to DynamoDB, utilizing promises. I get no errors, but the function doesn't move past the call to Dynamo. Similar questions I have found seemed to be resolved by using promises, so I feel this is a new question.

I have tried using promises with then statements to wait on DynamoDB to return data. I receive no errors, but my last log statement is right before the call to dynamo.

Here is my dynamo helper function:

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
//let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB() //This may get rid of the execption but gotta make it work. Think I have to wrap the data witht the types in dynamo
//let dynamoPromise = dynamo.promise()
let dynamoHelper = function() {
  return {
    putObject: function(tableName, object) { //,callback I took callback out of the params
      let params = {
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Item": object
      };

      let dynamoPromise = dynamo.put(params).promise()

      return dynamoPromise;
    },
    getRoom: function(tableName, deviceId) { //,callback I took callback out of the params
      console.log("inside the dynamoHelper.getRoom function")
      let params = {
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Key": {
          "deviceId": deviceId
        },
        "AttributesToGet": [
          "roomNumber"
        ]
      };
      let dynamoPromise = dynamo.get(params).promise() //? 
      console.log("After the get call to dynamo still inside dynamo helper")
      return dynamoPromise;
    }
  }
}();
module.exports = dynamoHelper;
```

Here is where I call it in index.js:

```
let dynamoGetPromise = dynamoHelper.getRoom(config.room_lookup_dynamodb_table, deviceId) //took the callback out of the args and put it in then. Will have to do the same for the one that is contained inside the then.
    dynamoGetPromise
      .then(
        function(data) {
          console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          if ('Item' in data) {
            roomNumber = data.Item.roomNumber;
          } else {
            roomNumber = 9999;
          }

...........
```

That `console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));` statement is never reached,
but -again- no errors. Shouldn't be a timeout issue as my Lambda output says billed duration is only 700ms...

Here is my lambda output:

`START RequestId: e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd Version: $LATEST
2019-04-04T14:30:52.075Z    e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd    Warning: Application ID is not set
2019-04-04T14:30:52.193Z    e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd    { canHandle: [Function: canHandle], handle: [Function: handle] }
2019-04-04T14:30:52.254Z    e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd    ||| New Session |||
2019-04-04T14:30:52.254Z    e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd    Device ID: amzn1.ask.device.AEH2LHYGV7GSPP5THMR5H56AI2OOMAQ7MF54CZ3E6WR433WGS6QAOCYCKJWRJ3TQY5IE76NWR2IKCANB6TJNKLDEZOO2YN6ACUVT33MKSS4CO6R7GJI6GDFLOBOPUA2IXX7RI732UXJ6PDST5KYC7CSQK634K4APEBRNVOKVZIDECOCBBIFB4
2019-04-04T14:30:52.254Z    e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd    New Intent Time: 2019-04-04T10:30:52-04:00
2019-04-04T14:30:52.254Z    e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd    inside the dynamoHelper.getRoom function
END RequestId: e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd
REPORT RequestId: e57c0e7a-bdf2-4e20-869b-44babf834dfd  Duration: 693.31 ms Billed Duration: 700 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB`

Thanks for any help!

Update:

Added a catch statement directly to the dynamo.get call, and still no more info:

`let dynamoPromise = dynamo.get(params).promise().catch(function(reason){console.log("Reason: " +  reason)});`

Update2:

Tried getting rid of the IIFE, and turning them into async functions held in an object. Same results.

Tried @alex067's suggestion below, but same results.

Update3:

I have solved ~90% of my issue using async/await.

Comment: Try changing it to: 

let request = dynamo.get(params)
return request.promise()

Comment: @alex067 Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't change my outcome at all. :/

Comment: This question pretty much sums up my #1 frustration with AWS/Dynamo.  Massively frustrating, and after over a year working with AWS/Lambda/Dynamo, I still don't know why this happens sometimes.  "Futz with it until it works" has been the only resolution, and that is not acceptable to me.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me please what how you solved this issue exactly? I am facing the exact same one. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Sandro_V Hey, instead of using vanilla promises I went with the async/await approach. I can't remember at this point what my problem even was... but I suggest you start learning about async/await if you haven't, and try that instead of creating your own promises: https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/truly-understanding-async-await-491dd580500e